# SQL Server Add a uniqueidentifier to every table in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I created a C# app with a SQL Server 2014 backend. I was only intending to use the app for myself but now I have interest from other users. I never had the forethought to add a user id to any of the tables and my question is how could generate a script to add a uniqueid column to all the tables. I don't want to create a new database for every user and would prefer that every table has a unique column for the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'alter table ? add new_guid uniqueidentifier null';
```

Comment: Unfortunately this sp does not exist in SQL Azure but can be capied from 2014 express but it does depend on another sp  which can be copied and renamed sys.sp_MSforeach_worker.